# Scanning Names and weird Strings: Files

Tags: c, arrays, file, char

Im doing an assignment to sort names in a list that is located inside a text file. I am using CodeBlocks v17.12. I am asking the code to read in the first name (which in this case happens to be Hamza) on the file and when it sees a space it should stop. However once I compile it in CodeBlocks it spits out: ``` Hamza uyªn<■   ║kDu¡lDu``@ ```

Does anyone know what this issue is? I can`t have it there as I will need to sort names out later on.

```
{
    fPointerOne = fopen("DT265A.txt", "r");
    fPointerTwo = fopen("DT265C.txt", "r");
    fPointerThree = fopen("DT265B.txt", "r");
    fPointerFour = fopen("DT8900.txt", "r");

    fgets(firstNames, 11, fPointerOne);
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        ClassGroup1.firstName[i] = firstNames[i];
        if (firstNames[i] == ' ') {
            goto PRINT;
        }
    }
  PRINT:
    printf("%s", ClassGroup1.firstName);

    fclose(fPointerOne);
    fclose(fPointerTwo);
    fclose(fPointerThree);
    fclose(fPointerFour);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm reasonably certain your code doesn't add a null-terminator to `ClassGroup1.firstName`, which makes `printf("%s", ClassGroup1.firstName);`exhibit *undefined behavior*

Comment: I think you need to  use fflush(stdin) ie clear buffer

Comment: Also that `goto` is absolutely unnecessary, just use a `break`

Comment: @UnholySheep you are correct

Comment: @UnholySheep Sheep, do you have any idea how I could add a null terminator (\0) into this?

Comment: Assuming you still have free space in `ClassGroup1.firstName` (which I can't tell because you didn't provide a [mcve])  you could just add `ClassGroup1.firstName[i + 1] = '\0'` inside the `if`

Comment: @AmitojSinghAhuja,  regarding: *fflush(stdin)*  In the C standard, this is specifically stated to be Undefined Behavior.

Answer (score 0):

In your loop, you copy all the characters up to the space, but never write the terminating '\0' character to ClassGroup1.firstName.  So when you print, you are printing all the garbage after the name up until the first 0x00 character in memory.

Also, the 11 in the fgets probably should be SIZE from this code snippet.  And a break would be better than the goto.

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. performs the indicated functionality
2. cleanly compiles
3. properly checks for errors
4. removes unused statements

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


#define MAX_NAMES    100
#define MAX_NAME_LEN 30
#define MAX_BUFFER_LEN 1024


struct CLASS_GROUP
{
    char firstName[ MAX_NAME_LEN ];
};


int main( void )
{
    struct CLASS_GROUP ClassGroup1[ MAX_NAMES ] = {'\0'};
    char inputBuffer[ MAX_BUFFER_LEN ];

    FILE *fPointerOne = fopen("DT265A.txt", "r");
    if( !fPointerOne )
    {
        perror( "fopen to read DT265A.txt failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //FILE *fPointerTwo = fopen("DT265C.txt", "r");
    //FILE *fPointerThree = fopen("DT265B.txt", "r");
    //FILE *fPointerFour = fopen("DT8900.txt", "r");

    int i = 0;
    while( i < MAX_NAMES && fgets( inputBuffer, sizeof( inputBuffer ) , fPointerOne) )
    {
        char * token;
        if( (token = strtok( inputBuffer, " " )) )
        {
            strcpy( ClassGroup1[i].firstName, token);
        }

        i++;
    }

    printf("%s", ClassGroup1[0].firstName);

    fclose(fPointerOne);
    // fclose(fPointerTwo);
    // fclose(fPointerThree);
    // fclose(fPointerFour);
    return 0;
}
```